# jQuery: Chrome Issue

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

I have the following section of jQuery but for some reason it does not like Chrome  why?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    var subMenu = jQuery("li ul li");
    var linkClick = jQuery("ul li").filter(":has(ul)");

    subMenu.hide();

    linkClick.click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        subMenu.slideToggle();
    });
});​
```

Comment: Please define: 'Does not like Chrome'

Comment: @GlennSlaven it just doesn't work,  Works fine in FF

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: If you put a breakpoint on the 1st line after the `ready` function, does it hit?

Comment: @GlennSlaven I am going to script but its not letting me add the BP

Comment: Is this live somewhere, or can you put it up on http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @GlennSlaven  http://jsfiddle.net/MGhMB/ and it works there lol.  I would also like to remove the slide affect if possible and just have it show hide on click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really don't know why it's not working for you, but I can answer the slide issue, just change `subMenu.slideToggle();` to `subMenu.toggle();`

Comment: Thanks for that,  Another question the link that I click on to launch the drop down is also a page I tried to remove the `  e.preventDefault();` but the menu just does not stay down

Comment: Well it wouldn't because it would follow the link to the new page.  You can't have it triggering a dropdown *and* be a link to a new page.